SpringBoot Transactional not respecting FOR UPDATE
I have a SpringBoot application with a Postgres database. One of the endpoints on my controller is a DELETE /item/{id} while the other is a GET /item/{id}.
Both of these call a different service layer method with the @Transactional annotation on them. The get method then calls the default JPA repository method, findById(id), whereas the delete method first acquires a row level lock via the JPA method:
@Query("SELECT * FROM item WHERE id = :id FOR UPDATE", nativeQuery= true)
Optional<Item> findByIdWithLock(Integer id);

After getting the item via this method, it runs a 10 second timer before calling the default delete method. The timer is to test that locking works. I'm also using a native query since @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) generates a for no key update when using Postgres for some reason.
I would expect that calling the get within 10 seconds would wait for the delete to finish, however it runs instantly.
Any ideas?

How exactly did you test that? Did you try a concurrent SELECT ... FOR UPDATE? By the way, it should be FOR NO KEY UPDATE.

Just curl requests to my endpoints. Concurrent SELECT ... FOR UPDATEs block each other but I was hoping to just block all reads including non locked reads

You cannot block concurrent reads, and then why would you? They won't see dirty data, but they will see the consistent state of the database from before the transaction.

This is how Multi-Version Concurrency Control (MVCC) works in PostgreSQL. When you send a SELECT FOR UPDATE query, PostgreSQL creates a copy of the data you are querying, and your transaction operates on that copy. If another transaction send a SELECT query before your transaction completes, PostgreSQL will access the original data instead of your copy, which will avoid blocking. However, if another transaction send SELECT FOR UPDATE query, PostgreSQL will pause that transaction until your transaction completes.

in fact, physical changes in the database occur not after the SELECT FOR UPDATE query, but of course after UPDATE or DELETE, but for simplicity of explanation we can consider that for each transaction its own virtual snapshot of the data is created


Oh I see. So does that mean SELECT FOR UPDATE and @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) don't actually work as intended (don't lock the row for reads) when using a Postgres DB?

Also does Postgres automatically lock rows during updates and deletes? Does this mean I shouldn't bother with specifying row level locks in my application

This explanation is incorrect about the mechanism of FOR UPDATE locking. No copying is occurring. However the lock will only prevent changes to the rows locked. See the section of the manuals covering locking and transaction levels.

@AnthonySeager SELECT FOR UPDATE works exactly as intended, locking the record from being modified by other transactions.

@AnthonySeager I think at the application level you should use Hibernate's optimistic locking mechanism and avoid locks at the database level.

@AndreySmelik how would you suggest I prevent a row from being read while it's being deleted?

@AnthonySeager What problem are you trying to solve by blocking reading?

The deleting function needs to do a couple things before deleting from the repository. This may take a couple seconds and I would rather a get request waits those couple seconds first

@AnthonySeager I think your app's clients won't appreciate waiting a few seconds. But if you want to break performance, do SELECT FOR UPDATE for methods get and delete.
